# class 'CouchbaseCluster' not found in apache's error log

Tags: php, json, installation, couchbase

Hello people I'm trying to install The Couchbase PHP SDK but for some reason PHP is not found the class.

I wrote `extension=json.so` and `extension=json.so` in PHP ini.

`Pecl info` doesn't show me anything about couchbase and `php -m` shows me that the extension is loaded.

I don't know what happened, can you help me please?

Comment: how did you install extension? what OS do you use? what version of PHP and what version of the extension?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.10 and  PHP 7. I followed the instructions fro this page : (https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html) .... but i couldn't dowloand **couchbase-release-1.0-2-amd64.deb** so I downloaded the **couchbase-release-1.0-2-x86_64.rpm**

Comment: okay. how did you installed PHP extension for Couchbase? Did you use `pecl install couchbase`?

Comment: yes i did it too, I think is something wrong with  the extension because  in the phpinfo there is nothing about couchbase